# How do I get Mockito to return a specific instance?

Tags: mockito

I can't tell if this is supported functionality. I want to mock the behavior when an object is provided to a mocked method. [Examples for "when"](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing) are given for integers or strings in the documentation, but can this be done for objects. Does a [custom matcher](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers) class need to be defined for each desired return object?

```
Class Point
   Point (int X, int Y)

Class ItemMover
   goEast(Point p) {
      return new Point(p.getX() + 1, p.getY())

Class App
   ItemMover itemMover
   Point currentPosition
   main() {
      def p1 = new Point(1,1)
      currentPosition = itemMover.goEast(p1)

Class AppTest
      def itemMover = Mock(ItemMover)
      def p1 = new Point(1,1)
      def p2 = new Point(2,1)
      when(itemMover.goEast(p1)).thenReturn(p2)
      app.main()
      assertEquals(app.currentPosition.getX(), 2)
```

**Update**: Based on answers below. The equals and hashCode methods for the object need to be implemented to evaluate equality as p1.equals(p2) when X and Y are equal.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  It seems unusual that you're calling a `mockPoint` method in your assert.  If your system under test is also your mock, all you're testing is that you mocked your code correctly, you aren't testing any real code.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is more complicated but this simplification produced jeff-bowman's answer which is exactly what I was looking for. A closer approximation of my problem would be a User object, a UserCredentials object and an Authentication service. I'm leaning toward not using Mockito but rather a custom mock Authentication service that will provide different Users object scenario's based on key values in the UserCredentials.

Comment: This question was down voted because the example was not real world usage of Mockito. I revised the example to more clearly demonstrate the use case. Thanks again to @jeff-bowman and Max Fichtelmann who were able to guess at what I was after in the first revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can return object instances the same way you return primitive values.
2. You will not need a custom Matcher *as long as* you override `equals` and `hashCode` on the object in question (Point). Mockito, by default or with the `eq` matcher, will use the object's `equals` method to determine whether objects are equal—and without an override only equal references (`==`) will be seen as equal. If any Point(2, 3) equals any other Point(2, 3), this is the right place and time to express that.

   Point is an especially good candidate for overriding `equals` and `hashCode`, as point equality is well-defined and easy to compute, and does not rely on external services or data. Argument matchers are an excellent solution for trickier objects than Points.
3. As tieTYT mentioned, it's rare to call a stub method in an assertion. For any given test, ensure you know which single system or object you're testing, use mocks *around* that object to give it a predictable environment, and then test that you get either expected values or expected calls on the mocks. Calling a mock in an assertion usually results in a confusing, brittle, or tautological test.

   Here, if you're testing Point, you probably don't need a mock—especially not a mock Point. If you were testing Maze, you still wouldn't need a mock Point, because you could use real, tested Points. However, testing Game might require a mock Maze, so your test could be simpler and deterministic if the Maze were complex or random.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That explains well how Mockito is matching the parameter. I was surprised that the introduction didn't include any examples of matching POJO parameters. It wasn't clear if that was supported.

Comment: Glad to help! Do note that POJO equality is yours to define--it doesn't have to depend on all properties, but should be [consistent](http://javapapers.com/core-java/hashcode-and-equals-methods-override/). Hamcrest does have a matcher ([hasPropertyWithValue](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.java?r=228)) built in for matching objects by bean property value; then your code looks like `when(mockPoint.goEast(argThat(hasPropertyWithValue("x", equalTo(2))))).thenReturn(p4);`. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can use concrete arguments as well as argument matchers with any object. So this should work fine.

```
when(mockPoint.goEast(p1)).thenReturn(p3)
```

It configures the mock to return `p3` when `p1` is used as argument. To combine it with argument matchers (since concrete arguments and matchers may not be mixed), I usually use the default `eq` matcher.

```
// assuming a second goEast method with an int parameter
when(mockPoint.goEast(eq(p1), anyInt())).thenReturn(p3)
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I didn't frame the problem very well but I was trying to understand how p5 = new Point(1,1) would also produce p3.